# Dynamically find the address at which the kernel is loaded

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'd like to be able to programmatically find out the address at which the linux kernel is loaded. If there are tools out there that already do that, I'd be willing to use them. However, inspecting the `PARAMS_PHYS` field in the `.config` during the kernel build is not an option. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where do you want to find it? From kernel space or user space? If you want to get it from userspace you can parse output of the `/proc/iomem`:

```
cat /proc/iomem | grep "Kernel code"
01000000-0168b523 : Kernel code
```

If you want to get it from kernel space, you can `__pa_symbol` macro which returns physical address of a given symbol. In your case you will need to do something like this:

```
__pa_symbol(_text)
```